# Insert character value in specific row/column of a pre-assigned data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a pre-assigned data frame to hold some output data:

```
d  = data.frame(a=character(5), b=numeric(5))
```

I am trying to assign values to specific rows of `d$a`:

```
d$a[3] = "foo"
```

Which  works fine for the numeric fields, but inserts `NA` rather than the value because it is expecting a factor:

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, 3, value = c(1L, 1L, NA, 1L, 1L)) :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

How can I insert the correct value?

Comment: Use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` inside of your `data.frame` so that column "a" isn't converted to `factor`.

Comment: Argh. RTFM; skimmed it but missed it!

Comment: And to avoid further factor frustration: set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `options` in your R profile. See [Initialization at Start of an R Session](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Startup.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic case of where you may want to remember to use `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` when creating your `data.frame`.

Alternatively, you can manually add the missing level before trying to make the replacement. (For example, `levels(d$a) <- c(levels(d$a), "foo")`).

Try the following examples:

```
d <- data.frame(a=character(5), b=numeric(5), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
d$a[3] <- "foo"

e <- data.frame(a=character(5), b=numeric(5))
levels(e$a) <- c(levels(e$a), "foo")
e$a[3] <- "foo"
```